# How to replace a block of text with special characters using preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm using the following:

```
$pattern_array = array();
$replace_array = array();
$pattern_array[] = '#\[vc_row][vc_column width="1/2" css=".vc_custom_1503896034143{margin-bottom: 40px !important;}"][shortcode_testimonials_carousel#i';
$replace_array[] = '[vc_row fixed_width="true"][vc_column width="1/2" css=".vc_custom_1503896034143{margin-bottom: 40px !important;}"][shortcode_testimonials_carousel';
echo preg_replace($pattern_array, $replace_array, $content);
```

To replace this text:

```
[vc_row][vc_column width="1/2" css=".vc_custom_1503896034143{margin-bottom: 40px !important;}"][shortcode_testimonials_carousel
```

With this text:

```
[vc_row fixed_width="true"][vc_column width="1/2" css=".vc_custom_1503896034143{margin-bottom: 40px !important;}"][shortcode_testimonials_carousel
```

But I get the error:

```
preg_replace(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 69
```

I don't need any regex rules or anything, I just want to replace one block of text with another ignoring all the [square brackets] and "quotemarks", is there any way to do this with preg_replace?

On a side note, I know I could use str_replace, but I'm adding this in a function which is looping through an array and already using preg_replace so str_replace is not an option.

Comment: WHY are you using preg_replace on a static replace?

Comment: Read the last sentance in my question

Comment: Doesn't matter. You are looping so? It's still a str_replace you need. Use the correct tool.

Comment: Do you gain anything posting useless responses like this? If you don't know the solution why bother responding?

Comment: @Andreas I think he's saying that other elements of the array are not static replacements, and he's trying to use the same method for all of them.

Comment: Exactly Barmar, spot on

Comment: Still not a reason to use the wrong tool in my opinion. Str_replace will run faster so having the static replacements in a str_replace and the dynamic in preg_replace is a better option. It's still the same number of function calls done, only one way is faster than the other.

Comment: If I have to loop through all the data again just to use str_replace that'll be faster? I don't think so. If it's the "wrong tool" what is the preg_quote function for?

Comment: Don't be a jerk. It's not about looping the same values twice. Your pattern_array should be split in two. One with the static and one with the dynamic. For example, let's say it's 3+3. That means you run str_replace on three and preg_replace on three. And yes that is faster and uses less memory since you are not using all the overhead of the preg functions. And preg_quote is not supposed to be used as a patch for poorly written code. It escapes regex characters, but properly made code runs just as fine without preg_quote.

Comment: I can't use str_replace, I clearly mentioned this in my question. The problem has already been solved perfectly by Karol Samborski so I'm honestly not sure what you're trying gain at this point.

Comment: I'm trying to teach you how to make a code that runs faster but apparently it's useless. Keep digging buddy.

Comment: See here a mix of str_replace and preg_replace that is as you say impossible. https://3v4l.org/hR9rF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape special characters used in regexes. There is this great function called `preg_quote` that will do it automatically.

```
$pattern_array = array();
$replace_array = array();
$pattern_array[] = '#' . preg_quote('[vc_row][vc_column width="1/2" css=".vc_custom_1503896034143{margin-bottom: 40px !important;}"][shortcode_testimonials_carousel', '#') . '#i';
$replace_array[] = '[vc_row fixed_width="true"][vc_column width="1/2" css=".vc_custom_1503896034143{margin-bottom: 40px !important;}"][shortcode_testimonials_carousel';
echo preg_replace($pattern_array, $replace_array, $content);
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea preg_quote existed, thanks very much for the insightful answer